# Azure logic apps: Exporting large data from database into CSV file

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am working on Azure Logic App based solution to export the data from Database to CSV file.

So far, I am able to do the following:

1. Use SQL database connector and execute the stored procedure to retrieve data
2. Create a CSV file
3. Use FTP connector to upload the file to an FTP server

With this approach, the issue is going to be data size. I am trying to figure out a way(s) to handle large data export. Here are the different approaches I can think of:

Option 1: Use pagination in SP, and iteratively collect the data.

Question 1.1: In each loop in the Logic App, multiple CSV files will be generated. How to combine the data from each iteration into a single CSV file?

Question 1.2: I am thinking of using a variable array to collect the data from each iteration, and then create CSV file from the variable array. Will I run into any issue if the size of the variable array becomes too large?

Option 2: Somewhere I read that you can overcome the data size issue with chunking.

Question: I am not even sure if the database connector supports chunking and will I able export the data into a single CSV file?

Option 3: Create multiple CSV files and then merge them into one CSV file?

Question: Is that possible to do it in Logic apps? Or will I need to implement a Logic function to handle the merging of CSV files?

Comment: Have you looked at Azure Data Factory instead of Logic Apps? This is exactly the kind of workflow it is designed to handle.

Comment: @JoelCochran, you are right, DF is more suitable than Logic Apps. But was exploring the Logic apps for this as it can be easily configured by the Business analyst.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say different options without knowing the amount of data you are talking about.

1- Yes you can use pagination, i would recommend using a SP in your sql server to return the data and also the page size and number: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40060.sql-pagination-for-bulk-data-transfer-with-logic-apps.aspx

1.1 By default for-each in LogicApps is executed in parallel, check the For each settings and change the concurrency control: https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#foreach-loop-sequential

The data returned from the SP can be converted to csv by using "create csv table"
https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#create-csv-table-action